# Como armazenar apenas caracteres de um arquivo de texto em um vetor?

Tags: c

```
int main(){
char aux;
int i=0,j=0,p=0;
char vetor[26];

FILE *arq;
```

> Meu arquivo.txt possui uma string qualquer, quero apenas pegar os caracteres dessa string e passar para um vetor de 26 posiçoes, que é a quantidade de letras que tem no alfabeto. Nao vem ao caso agora, mais futuramente irei implemetar uma funçao para nao ter caracteres repetidos.

```
arq = fopen("arquivo.txt","r");
```

> No while eu pecorro todo o arquivo de texto e retiro os '\n' e armazeno o resto no vetor

```
while (fscanf(arq, "%c", &aux )!= EOF){
    printf("%d %c\n",i++ ,aux);
    if(aux != '\n'){
       vetor[j] = aux;
       j++;
    }
}
printf("Print do vetor\n");
```

> Porem na hora que vou printar todas as posiçoes do vetor ainda aparece uns espaços vazios que eu nao sei oque é, e nem como tratalos. Segue uma imagem abaixo

```
for ( p = 0; p < j; p++){
    printf("%c\n", vetor[p]);
}


fclose(arq);
return 0;
```

}
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está o arquivo original (arquivo.txt) ?

Comment: AABCDD
BADCC
FABD
XFCX

Comment: cada espaço é uma quebra de linha(nao conseguir enviar com quebra de linha)

Comment: Testando aqui no meu pc aparece correto. Voce tem a certeza que tem quebras de linha normais no seu arquivo de entrada ?

Comment: sim, possuir 4 linhas e cada linha tem uma string

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQcVD.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQcVD.png)

Comment: estranho , mas obg pelo tempo , vou tentar ver com calma aqui , vlw

Comment: vlw mano, foi oque eu tava pesando, apenas dei um espaço entre  " e o % na funçao fscanf